# Halt and set fire to the [sysadmin]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[sysadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin) has 399 questions, [33 of which](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsysadmin%5D%20closed%3Ayes) are closed. Its description is:

> A person responsible for maintaining the running health of a system (usually an electronic computer). Questions about system administration generally belong on Super User or Server Fault.

Following the [process to burninate tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/4174897), here are the answers to [the four criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392):

1. #### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   ... Maybe? This tag is about a specific job, so one could argue that it's about the kind of stuff that a sysadmin does..? Sysadmins are fairly busy people though, so there is indeed ambiguity as to *what is being treated in a specific question*.
2. #### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   As can be read in the tag description itself, no. Questions about the job itself have nothing to do on Stack Overflow, and questions about system administration are better on SU / SF.
3. #### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   System administration cover an incredibly wide range of scopes and technologies. This tag adds no meaningful information at all.
4. #### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   I can spot two meanings: The sysadmin job / career, or system administration in general. Most related tags are [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) (94, or a little shy of a fourth of all questions) and [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) (30). This data and my personal experience watching this tag indicate that it's mostly used in the *system administration* context.

I do not see how this tag could be salvaged or cleaned.
Anyone got matches?

---

Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed.

---

Fun fact: Joel [created the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sysadmin/info) 7 years ago.
[HCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire) reference.

Comment: If anyone has a better (read: funnier) link for that last reference, please do edit it in.

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: @Kyll [TIS-100](http://www.zachtronics.com/tis-100/) Has an HCF easter egg, use that one instead.

Comment: There is also [tag:system-administration]

Answer (score 3):

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I think that is the crux of why it should be burninated. I think it is a vary broad term, and doesn't add anything.